# Pine script and trading view closing entry with wrong ID

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm testing pine editor and the strategy tester for the first time, but I'm stack trying to understand and unexpected behaviour.

Below is the code of a simple strategy that I'm testing. (Basically I would like to understand the difference between strategy.close and strategy.exit) So in order to do that I simply buy on Monday and close the position on Friday. To really test the close position I enter a new position on Wednesday and I expect that the code should never close the Wednesday position. But, if I check the "List of Trades" of the "Strategy Tester" I can see that in the trade number 2 the Wednesday position is closed by the Monday closing order. (see attached image).

Can someone clarify why this is happening? Also I noticed that the buy signal on Monday happens on Tuesday even though I have the process_orders_on_close activated (otherwise it happens on Wednesday) and the same with all the week days.

Thanks for your help.
Cheers.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true, pyramiding=2)


testStartYear = input(2021, "Backtest Start Year")
testStartMonth = input(06, "Backtest Start Month")
testStartDay = input(06, "Backtest Start Day")
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)

// Stop us from entering two wednesday positions when pyramiding is on
// This would prevent us entering a monday position.
wedEntered = bool(na)
wedEntered := nz(wedEntered[1], false)

monCondition = time >= testPeriodStart and dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
wedCondition = time >= testPeriodStart and dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday and (not wedEntered[1])

if (monCondition)

    strategy.entry("Monday", strategy.long)
    // strategy.exit("Monday TP", "Monday", limit=high)
    
if (wedCondition)
    wedEntered := true
    strategy.entry("Wednesday", strategy.long)

strategy.close("Monday", when=dayofweek == dayofweek.friday)
// strategy.close_all(when=dayofweek == dayofweek.friday)
```

[image: Strategy Tester]

Comment: I suggests to start from reading https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html

Comment: Thanks @AndreyD for the link, I appreciate it, but it doesn't really help on solving the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 3):

You need specify `close_entries_rule` parameter like this:

```
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true, pyramiding=2, close_entries_rule="ANY")
```